# Question about the use of 察す

Tags: verbs, particle-と

I was reading a light novel, and this sentence came up, is と here working as quotation with 察して? and what can the verb in this situation mean?

むしろ追いかけられていると察して、逃げ足を速めるに違いない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

察して is the te-form of 察する, and it is one of the verbs that take quotative-と. The meaning is "to notice/understand/guess (some fact, indirectly via a circumstantial evidence, a facial expression, etc)". The と-clause contains what is noticed/understood.

> 追いかけられていると察する
>   to notice they are chased *(not by actually seeing the chaser but by seeing some indirect evidence)*